# Customize Devise redirect if already signed_in user tries to sign up again

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, devise

I feel like this is super easy...

I've done very little customization to the default Devise Controllers, the customization in my Registrations#New is designed to ensure certain variables are accessible in the view. I've read the source code, but not sure I'm seeing the line that redirects the user if the user that's visiting the sign up page is already sign in?

Basically if a user is already signed in, if s/he visits the sign up page, I want to redirect him/her to the dashboard page. Currently, the redirect is going to the root page.

How can I change this?

My code:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def new
  gon.zipcode_list = zipcode_list
  gon.all_invite_codes = all_invite_codes
  selected_plan_array 
  meal_type_array 

  super
end
end
```

Source code:

```
def new
  build_resource({})
  set_minimum_password_length
  yield resource if block_given?
  respond_with self.resource
end
```

Routes:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations", sessions: "users/sessions" }

root "staticpages#home" 
#^ the above is where a user is being redirected if s/he is already signed in and visiting the sign up page
```

Basically I'd love something like the below

```
def after_existing_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  dashboard_path
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code in the source code that redirects the user is the filter :require_no_authentication. If you overwrite the Devise::SessionsController to skip that filter, you will be able to redirect your user your chosen path.

Like so:

```ruby
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  # Note that all the other actions are handled by Devise::SessionsController
  # (which is in the gem)
  skip_filter :require_no_authentication, only: :new
  def new
    if user_signed_in?
      redirect_to dashboard_path
      return
    end
    super
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm using rails 6, and got this working with `skip_before_action :require_no_authentication, only: :new`.
Also, the original question was asking about registration, I think this should be in `class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`.